# What's the difference between A portrait of my mother and my mother's portrait?

Tags: difference, possessives

> There's a portrait of my mother in that room.

> There's my mother's portrait in that room.

Are the both sentences the same in the meaning?

Comment: Can you add some context around your examples?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes and no. Both the sentence do logically mean the same thing, but grammatically the second sentence can mean possesion (according to grammar rules) if followed by "**of**". Like: "**It's my mother's portrait of me and my sister**" - means that she made this portrait.

The first construction, that is "**a portrait of**" is more common.

Answer (score 0):

They are not quite the same in meaning, although they can be equivalent depending on context.

"portrait of my mother" unambiguously means a portrait that depicts my mother.

However, "my mother's portrait" can mean either a portrait depicting my mother or a portrait of any subject either owned or created by my mother.

It is impossible to tell which without additional context.

Answer (score -1):

Though both the sentences convey the same message, there is a *negligible* difference in using apostrophe over the 'of clause'.

I am not sure, but I feel that with animated subjects, the apostrophe is preferred or *at least is more common.*

> There is my *mother's portrait* in that room (animated subject) ***but*** 
>  The <del>*car's color*</del> color of car is red (inanimate subject).

[Note: Don't consider this as a *concrete rule!*]